# How to fix soft 404 errors in GWT?

Tags: google-search-console, soft-404

In GWT I have been receiving soft 404 errors for some URLs of my online shopping website. Ichecked all those URLs and those pages are looking good and there is nothing wrong in that page. Then why I'm receiving that errors?

This is the notification that I received in my GWT:

> Dear owner or webmaster,
>
> While crawling your site, we have noticed an increase in the number of
>   transient soft 404 errors around 2013-06-30 16:00 UTC (London, Dublin,
>   Edinburgh). Your site may have experienced outages. These issues may
>   have been resolved.

Comment: As mentioned in the message, perhaps there was some down time just at that specific time.  I'd mark the the issues as fixed. If they come again then look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message means, that 2013-06-30 16:00 UTC from London, Dublin, Edinburgh your pages were not accessible for googlebot. And if they are good now, you should not worry about that.

I had gotten the same messages and my pages were ok too. I had not issues with it in future.